# How to run python script in windows backround?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, background

I have a python script that running on windows server 2008 on cmd line. I don't need any interact during script running. By the way the script is running during about a week. So if the server disconnects my connection for some reason, my script stops and I have to start over and over again. It is huge trouble for me and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Here is my question.

How to run a python script in backround on windows server even user disconnect from the server?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this is a question about daemon process, which runs in the background. you should google it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629813/is-there-windows-analog-to-supervisord

Answer (score 1):

You may use my own solution to do it under Windows: https://github.com/fomalhaut88/pydaemon. All you need is to create a class that runs the function from your script. The advantage of this approach is that you can add many other daemon processes and control them through `pydaemon`.

If it looks too heavy and complicated for you, you may wrap your script with an infinite loop in order to avoid stopping if it fails:

```
# yourscript.py
while True:
    try:
        ... # doing your stuff
    except:
        pass
```

To start it in background you may use following command:

```
start /MIN "" python yourscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your want to hide your running window?

Write a vbs script to run your python script.
Create a file named start.vbs

```
    Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    ws.run "cmd /c python your_python_script.py",0
```

Then you can double click start.vbs to run your script backround.

Comment: Any idea what VBS I could write to terminate the script?

Answer (score -1):

try to spin up an AWS instance and run it on a more reliable server. Or you can look into hadoop to process the code across multiple fail-safe servers