# Python - how do I make a program run forever, no matter what exceptions occur?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've got something of the form:

```
def func():
  while True:
    do_stuff()

try:
  func()
except:
  func()
```

I had expected that if anything happened to my func loop, it would start again, however in actual fact errors cause it to crash. How can I make it just restart if anything goes wrong?

Comment: I think you should rely on shell script for this matter.

Comment: So you program will still work on out of memory exceptions?

Comment: @RedX  can we do it like: use all the exception except `out of memory` exception? in python?

Comment: @Nihal Of course you can always make a whitelist or blacklist but my point is that the simple requirement shows no real thought and should be reconsidered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try placing the `try-except` inside a `while` loop and use `pass` in the except block.

**Ex:**

```
def func():
  while True:
    do_stuff()

while True:
    try:
        func()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Keeping a program run is generally not the responsibility of the program itself.  If you are on a UNIX-like operating system, you can use [Supervisord](https://serversforhackers.com/c/monitoring-processes-with-supervisord) to automatically run processes and let them restart if they fail. If you are on Windows, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630199) may help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put loop contents inside try except statements

```
def func():
    while True:
        try:
            do_stuff()
        except:
            continue
func()
```