# Supervisor(or similar tool) for Python3.7 in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, devops, supervisord

I have used Supervisor for ubuntu which is pretty simple and easy to use. 
However now I want to execute a python script persistently on a windows machine.

I tried installing supervisor by using the below command

```
pip install supervisor
```

but getting the following error

```
Supervisor requires Python 2.4 or later but does not work on any version of 
Python 3.  You are using version 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 
23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)].  Please install using a supported 
version.
```

Is there a way to install supervisor on python 3.7.2? or are there any alternative solutions in windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there Windows analog to supervisord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629813/is-there-windows-analog-to-supervisord)

Comment: @ohlr Its a 7 year old answer and back then there was no pypi package for supervisor. In 2016 official supervisor package has been released and its only for python2

Comment: The answer is still valid: https://pypi.org/project/supervisor/ "Supervisor has been tested and is known to run on Linux (Ubuntu), Mac OS X (10.4, 10.5, 10.6), and Solaris (10 for Intel) and FreeBSD 6.1. It will likely work fine on most UNIX systems.

**Supervisor will not run at all under any version of Windows.**

Supervisor is known to work with Python 2.4 or later but **will not work under any version of Python 3.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a windows service. It helps you run the code consistently. You can try kubernetes as well.