# How to run laravel jobs as a service in windows server 2012 r2 and access the project publicly?

Tags: python, windows, laravel, iis, crud

I have set up a Laravel app in windows server 2012 but want to run jobs in it as windows services. So that it is always running on my server. I want my users to access it as a website publicly from any browser. 
Also, I would like to know how can I use python to perform crud operations as a service hosted on the same server.

Comment: do u know about cron job?

Comment: yes I do. But i have previously worked on nginx servers. So how do I go about it. I just wanted a tried and tested guideline on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run supervisor on your OS and mange your jobs.
[how to install supervisor on windows server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629813/is-there-windows-analog-to-supervisord)

The other solution is [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/) that help you run your queue process as windows service.

Please check [this question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-way-to-use-queues-on-a-windows-server) on Laracast.com